# news display modules height

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I am using a joomla module to display articles from 8 different categories, the module is displaying the title and some introtext for each category (the same module is used 8 times).

For example, one article has title that needs two rows to display - another needs just one and they are not displayed simetrically so my site looks messy!

The question is: **how to make my 8 modules to always have the same height, regardless of the rows needed for the title or introtext?**

I can count chars and set some limits for the title and introtext, but the number of rows needed will vary with the width of my font letters... I hope there is an another solution except char counting...

I hope the question is clear enough!
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Am I the only person whose eyes glaze over when I read any derivation of *"I'm using **X** framework to do **X**. How do I make this small change?"*

Comment: you just had to make this comment, haven't you? you are probably right, but something can be a big change for someone while it is just a small change for others... would appreciate if you offered some solution other than criticising me for asking! no hard feelings, i realize this was probably not the hardest question around here, but i just wanted to see how other people solve these kind of things. cheers :)

Comment: No criticism, just glazed eyes. Frameworks produce vastly better code than many people who don't use them. This just happened to be the one post where I voiced my inability to help in a comment :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a CSS issue (or I'm misunderstanding the question). If all the modules are of class 'module', then you need:

```
.module {height:200px; overflow:hidden;[more styles]}
```

Comment: yes, I can do it this way, I would like is to somehow dynamically detect the need to make the module with shorter title higher...

Comment: if you need to do this dynamically then JS/jquery is going to be your best option. Start with kdzwinel's code (assuming you are using jquery) which will set the all the the same size based on max value. Are you trying to also re-organized the order of the modules?

Comment: thanks guys, I have simplified it to myself by using css to make my title div the height of two rows (in my example 40px) and set the char limit for the title. Now I have my titles long enough, but will also need to watch while adding a new article in order not to mess the layout up. This should be just fine... Thank you both, Ben D and kdzwinel...

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over these modules, take their heights, pick the largest one and apply on all modules.

```
var max = 0;

$('div.title').each(function(i,item){
   var height = $(item).height();
   if(height > max) {
      max = height;
   }
});

$('div.title').css('height', max + 'px');
```

Comment: thank you, your answer is good! i have chosen to use a simpler solution this time!